# Count the number of occurrences of a character

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code which does the count of the occurrences of a character in a string:

```
window.pqp = dddddd.trim(); // THE WORD FROM THE DATABASE

window.tbInput = $('input[name="tbInput"]').val(); // THE INPUT BOX THAT RECEIVES A VALUE THAT IS INSERTED BY THE USER.
```

This is the code to count the occurence:

```
window.count = (pqp.match(tbInput) || []).length;
```

The word that comes is “`testal`” and the user types in the input-box the letter “`t`”, it should count `2` but instead it counts `1`.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: why my comment was removed?

Comment: I don't know, can you comment again please ? I want to read it and answer!

Comment: I had to do the following :
 var oleeee = pqp.split($('input[name="tbInput"]').val()).length - 1;